# Using Deep link to open app with external link

Tags: android, android-deep-link

I am trying to make my android app open when the user presses on a link to our website.
I was following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) documentation but it is not working for me as it always opens the browser instead of asking if I would like to continue with the browser or the app. What am I doing wrong?

here is my manifest

```
     <activity
        android:name=".presentation.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LegendaryCollectionsAndroid.NoActionBar"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

            <data 
                android:host="www.legendarycollections.net"
                android:path="/reset"
                android:scheme="https"></data>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: I think that this is the guide you are looking for https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing

Answer (score 1):

check your website association here.

[image]

Comment: the tool was a good recommendation but the file generator is broken so I used this instead https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator waiting for my web dev to publish the file to see if it works

Comment: Yes. Both are OK.